# How to determine the right TiDB and TiDB-Ansible version?

Tags: distributed-database, tidb

TiDB provides so many different versions and the documentation also mentions different versions for users to install. How to avoid choosing the wrong TiDB version and TiDB-Ansible version? What's the difference between various TiDB master versions?

Answer (score 2):

The TiDB community is highly active. After the 1.0 GA release, the engineers have been keeping optimizing and fixing bugs. Therefore, the TiDB version is updated quite fast. If you want to keep informed of the latest version, see [TiDB Weekly update](https://pingcap.com/weekly/).

If you have questions regarding which version to use, email to info@pingcap.com for more information or [file an issue](https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-ansible/issues/new).

It is recommended to deploy the TiDB cluster using the latest version of [TiDB-Ansible](https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-ansible), which will also be updated along with the TiDB version. TiDB has a unified management of the version number after the 1.0 GA release. You can view the version number using the following two methods:

- `select tidb_version()`
- `tidb-server -V`